# Problema Con Editor De Interfaz De Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento editar el diseño para pantallas mas pequeñas pero se cambia la configuración para **pantallas Nexus 7 o otras pantallas**  cuando apretó el menu del circulo rojo y selecciono la opción de otra pantalla de menor tamaño no sucede ningún cambio y siempre queda para pantallas Nexus 7 o otras de gran tamaño 
**¿Que puedo hacer para visualizar para otras pantallas mas pequeñas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para hacer que la imagen se adapte a las diferentes dimensiones de las pantallas de los dispositivos primero debes crear las siquientes carpetas dentro de "res" como se muestra a continuacion:
[image: crear carpetas layout dentro de res]

luego copiar todos los archivos .xml que esta en la carpeta layout y pegar en cada carpeta que se encuentra en las que estan dentro del recuadro rojo, en el android studio te aparecera una serie de paquetes dentro de la carpeta "res" como se encuentra en la siguiente imagen, por cada carpeta le abres los layout y podras ir ajustando de acuerdo a las dimensiones de las pantallas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]